# Calling an event from a third party plugin in my plugin

Tags: events

Trying to work out if I’m doing something wrong with catching an event from another plugin in my plugin.

I’m trying to use [amforms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms) “onSaveSubmission” event, so, in my plugin’s `init()` 
function i have

```
craft()->on('amForms.onSaveSubmission', function(Event $event) {
    var_dump($event);
});
```

But, when I submit a form successfully, this event is triggering an error:

```
Internal Server Error

Property "Craft\AmFormsService.onSaveSubmission" is not defined.
```

The `onSaveSubmission` event is in `/plugins/amforms/services/AmForms_SubmissionsService.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
craft()->on('amForms_submissions.saveSubmission', function(Event $event) {
    BusinessLogicPlugin::log(print_r($event, true));
});
```

Pay attention to the casing
`Craft\AmForms_SubmissionsService` → `amForms_submissions`

https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#listening-for-events

Comment: I've updated my question, i was wrong with what i was doing in the first instance.

Comment: `saveSubmission` not `onSaveSubmission`, see the linked docs article.

Comment: Right, gotcha! However, i've updated my code to amForms.saveSubmission and i'm still getting ```Internal Server Error

Property "Craft\AmFormsService.onSaveSubmission" is not defined.```

Comment: Just had a quick look at the plugins source code and updated the answer to what I think should work.

Comment: I'm not getting an error now, but also no data is being dumped. Not sure this is working either.

Comment: Try `MyPluginPlugin::log($event)` instead of dumping.

Comment: It's adding nothing to the log i'm afraid (and i do have devmode set to true!)